# Selenium tests executed via Maven shows Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 and BUILD SCUEESS even though some tests failed

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines

Selenium tests executed via Maven (via DevOps pipeline) shows Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 and BUILD SCUEESS even though some tests failed. I am working on Selenium WebDriver project. Below are the project details:

- I'm using Selenium WebDriver version 3.14.59
- Java version 17
- TestNG version 7.3.0
- Using Eclipse IDE version 2020-12 (4.18.0)
- I've integrated Extent Report for reporting requirement. Also using SQL queries in tests. Until now I was running my tests by right-clicking on a testng.xml file and the Console was showing this at the end of tests execution: Total Tests run: 110, Passes: 110, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

But now I have created a pipeline in DevOps. Then I created a BATCH file where I am using below command to run the testng.xml file:

mvn clean test -DtestngFile=<my_testng_file_name>

Here, at the end of tests execution, it don't show me how many tests ran, how many pass, failed, etc. Wondering why?

Also I tried running all 110 tests on my local machine using below command where it shows me the tests execution result as: Total Tests run: 110, Passes: 110, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

mvn clean test -DtestngFile=<my_testng_file_name>

Anyone have any idea?

I googled and tried different solutions but none worked so far.